# How to use class file instead of java file when compiling with maven

Tags: java, maven, class, compilation, pom.xml

We received an updated `.class` file but not the `.java` file for a project.  How can I ensure this new class file is used, and placed in the right directory, in the compiling of our `maven pom` without affecting the project?

Comment: Better ask for a JAR, not for unpackaged classes.

Comment: the service providing the files to me doesn't give jar files for these kinds of changes.  they expect us to manually make the changes to the java site post-deployment.

Comment: Sorry but receiving an single class file simply wrong way ...The transfer of things is done via jar files which usually have also a version which is related to a version control tag etc. to make it reproducible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best method, but i was able to accomplish using this class file as a replacement for .java and no .jar file being provided by adding this resource argument to the maven pom file.

```xml
<resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/action/helper</directory>
    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/classes/com/action/helper</targetPath>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting extracted class files is highly unusual. Normally, you get a jar and use it as dependency. In the case you have such class files, I would manually bundle them into a jar file and upload them to your Maven repository with appropriate coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version). Then you can reference them as dependency in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I think your solution is certainly viable, but I did not know how to package a class file into a jar back then, but I could do everything else you suggested. The solution I posted and accepted is what I've been using since.  Thanks for the tip, 